# in a series of n elements of arithmetic progression, [n/2] elements are changed. Find the difference in the initial arithmetic progression

Tags: algorithm, puzzle

I have a list of size n which contains n consecutive members of an arithmetic progression which are not in order. I changed less than half of the elements in this list with some random integer. From this new list, how can I find the difference of the initial arithmetic progression?

I thought a lot about it but except brute force, I was not able to come up with any other thing :(

Thanks for thinking on this one :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to solve this in general and be 100% sure that your answer is correct. Let's say that the initial list is the following arithmetic progression (not in order):

1 3 2 4

Change less than half the elements at random... let's say for example that we changed 2 to 5:

1 3 **5** 4

If we can first find out which numbers we need to change to obtain a valid shuffled arithmetic sequence then we can easily solve the problem stated in the question. However we can see that there are multiple possible answers depending in which we number we choose to change:

- **6**, 3, 5, 4 (difference is 1)
- 1, 3, **2**, 4 (difference is 1)
- 1, 3, 5, **7** (difference is 2)

There is no way to know which of these possible sequence is the original sequence, so you cannot be sure what the original difference was.

Comment: @Mark Byers- In this setup, you changed half the integers, but the OP mentions that you have to change *less* than half.  Does this still hold if less than half the values have been changed?

Comment: @Mark Byers- My mistake; I misread your post.  Sorry about that! +1. :-)

Comment: @templatetypedef: I think you are one of the smartest users on here so if you misread it probably most other people did too - this is a problem with my answer, not you. I've rewritten my answer slightly - hopefully it's a bit clearer now. Thanks for the comment. :)

Comment: Why isn't `1 3 5 7` correct? You don't know what the original sequence was (no access to `1 3 2 4`), so as far as you know it could be correct. Also, why only look at the first three elements? If you look at all of them there's no reason you can't come up with `1 2 3 4` too. I would say that there are multiple possible answers, not that it's impossible.

Comment: @IVlad: Your interpretation of the question could be written much more simply: *Given a list of n arbitrary integers find all the ways you can change less than half of them and then reorder them to form an arithmetic series.* But that's not what he is asking, IMHO.

Comment: I think he's only interested in **one** possible answer, which is why he mentioned he doesn't want a brute force solution. Maybe clarifications are in order.

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no deterministic solution for the problem (as stated by @Mark Byers), you can try a probabilistic approach.

It's difficult to obtain the original progression, but its rate can be obtained easily by comparing the differences between elements. The difference of original ones will be multiples of rate.

Consider you take 2 elements from the list (probability that both of them belongs to the original sequence is `1/4`), and compute the difference. This difference, with probability of 1/4, will be a multiple of the rate. Decompose it to prime factors and count them (for example, `12 = 2^^2 * 3` will add 2 to 2's counter and will increment 3's counter).

After many such iterations (it looks like a good problem for probabilistic methods, like [Monte Carlo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_method)), you could analize the counters.

If a prime factor belongs to the rate, its counter will be at least `num_iteartions/4` ( or `num_iterations/2` if it appears twice).

The main problem is that small factors will have large probability on random input (for example, the difference between two random numbers will have 50% probability to be divisible by 2). So you'll have to compensate it: since 3/4 of your differences were random, you'll have to consider that `(3/8)*num_iterations` of 2's counter must be ignored. Since this also applies to all powers of two, the simpliest way is to pregenerate "white noise mask" by taking the differences only between random numbers.

EDIT: let's take this approach further. Consider that you create this "white noise mask" (let's call it *spectrum*) for random numbers, and consider that it's base-1 spectrum, since their smallest "largest common factor" is 1. By computing it for a differences of the arithmetic sequence, you'll obtain a base-R spectrum, where `R` is the rate, and it will equivalent to a shifted version of base-1 spectrum. So you have to find the value of R such that

```
your_spectrum ~= spectrum(1)*3/4 + spectrum(R)*1/4
```

You could also check for largest number `R` such that at least half of the elements will be equal modulo `R`.